# Actionscript 3 onscreen keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard

I am creating an action script keyboard for a touch screen.
I have buttons from A - Z.

How do I get the value out of the mouse event?

```
Q.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, keyPressed);
W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, keyPressed);

function keyPressed(e:MouseEvent):void {

    trace("clicked " + value??);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class KeySprite which has a variable value and the key should be KeySprite :

```
public class KeySprite extands Sprite {

    public var value:String;

    public function KeySprite (value:String){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And the event catch will be :

```
function keyPressed(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(e.currentTarget is KeySprite){
        var currentKey:KeySprite = (KeySprite)e.currentTarget;
        trace("clicked " + currentKey.value);
    }
}
```